# Is this ruby on rails code thread safe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, thread-safety, jruby

I have an issue with `Logger` in JRuby on Rails app. One thread changes log level to error and  it does not change back. Is this code threadsafe, or should I look for other places where it is happening?

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/benchmarkable.rb#L50

```
def silence
  message = "ActiveSupport::Benchmarkable#silence is deprecated. It will be removed from Rails 4.1."
  ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn message
  old_logger_level, logger.level = logger.level, ::Logger::ERROR if logger
  yield
ensure
  logger.level = old_logger_level if logger
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, it looks like that during `yield` in first thread other thread will do `silence` it will have `logger.level` set to `ERROR`, so if other thread will end after first one, it will set level to `ERROR` permanently.

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered this very same thread safety problem with the Rails logger and JRuby. I don't know if you are looking for a workaround, but this fix worked for me: http://log.kares.org/2011/04/railslogger-is-not-threadsafe.html.

Comment: Thanks for link, this code is outdated now, but based on this I created my version.